# Elemento filho excedendo o elemento pai

Tags: css

Tenho um elemento filho que é montado dinamicamente, o conteúdo desse elemento as vezes pode ser comprido, isso faz com que tal elemento exceda o pai como no exemplo a seguir:

Elemento Pai:

```
margin: 5px 30px 10px 40px;
```

Elemento Filho:

```
$("#divcritica").append("<div id='divvalorcontabil"+ divvalorcontabil +"' class='operacao btn btn-info dashed-black-border' value='ValorContabil/"+marcados+"' style='margin:3px; 0px; 0px; 5px; box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 1px 7px -2px; border-radius: 3px; border: 2px;' ondblclick='removeButton(this)' onclick='setClass(this)'></div>");
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso ajustar para que nao exceda o elemento pai?

Obs: O conteúdo desse elemento é variavel.

Answer (score 2):

Aplique duas propriedades CSS ao botão (classe `.btn`):

```
.btn{
   word-break: break-all;
   white-space: normal;
}
```

Isso fará com que o texto ocupe apenas o espaço do botão, fazendo quebra de linha se necessário.

O `word-break: break-all;` irá quebrar textos longos que não caibam na largura do elemento. E o `white-space: normal;` é para alterar o valor padrão do Bootstrap, que usa `nowrap` (sem quebra de linha) na classe `.btn`.

Caso não queira alterar globalmente a classe nativa `.btn` do Bootstrap, você pode criar uma classe personalizada e adicionar no botão:

```
.quebralinha{
   word-break: break-all;
   white-space: normal;
}
```

> **Nota:** Se seu CSS estiver sendo carregado antes do `.css` do Bootstrap, você terá que usar `!important` após o valor das
>   propriedades para "anular" o efeito do CSS do Bootstrap. Ex.:
>   `white-space: normal !important;`

Exemplo:

```css
.btn{
   word-break: break-all;
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse6">
   PlanejamentoegestãodeprogramaseprojetossocioambientaisPlanejamentoegestãodeprogramaseprojetossocio ambientais
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rapaz eu não vou te dizer como resolver o problema, por existem 1000 formas para resolver. Eu vou te falar por que vc está tendo esse problema! É é por causa dessa classe `btn` do Bootstrp que vc está usando na `div`

A classe btn tem a propriedade `white-space: nowrap;` ela não deixa seu texto quebrar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma das forma de resolver e trocar `nowrap` por  `pre-wrap`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


  
  <div class='operacao btn btn-info dashed-black-border' style="white-space: pre-wrap;" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi amet ab eos qui earum est exercitationem voluptatibus error autem eum temporibus culpa, optio natus accusamus deserunt accusantium at sed recusandae reiciendis vero quas nihil praesentium? Fugiat doloribus cumque molestiae quis ipsum nesciunt, repellendus expedita veritatis odit alias fugit aliquid ea excepturi provident possimus culpa tempora delectus itaque. Deleniti ex debitis eligendi quam, ea voluptatibus rem velit eius rerum sapiente, earum commodi dolorem laborum ipsa enim ab hic assumenda dolores autem quia, voluptates corporis exercitationem. Aliquid impedit quae est non neque? Debitis repellendus dolores, soluta quam nam quisquam doloremque necessitatibus eos!</div>
```

Comment: Não use `pre-wrap` porque ele adiciona quebra de linha antes do elemento. E mesmo assim, essa propriedade sozinha não quebra o texto.

Comment: @Sam talvez eu tenha entendido errado isso *Sequências de espaço em branco são preservadas. Linhas são quebradas em caracteres de nova linha, em <br> e quando necessário para preencher as linhas das caixas  (boxes).* Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/white-space e pelo que vi ela preserva quebra de linha, espaços, <br> e sim faz o wrap http://prntscr.com/p5qn0v

Comment: Testando aqui, além de não quebrar o texto, ainda adiciona um `<br>` antes dele: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HxNv.png

Comment: Aliás, o print correto é esse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6OUd.png ... o outro print tem o `word-break` que quebra o texto.

Comment: @Sam aqui no Win10 e Chrome não adicionou BR não, além disso na pergunta dele ele usa uma div e não um button http://prntscr.com/p5qq75

Comment: Não adiciona um `<br>` no DOM, ele adiciona uma quebra de linha no início do elemento, como se fosse um <br>. Tanto faz div ou button, o efeito é o mesmo. A questão é que a sua resposta não resolve o problema :X

Comment: O `pre-wrap` ainda é mt ruim porque ele mantém os espaços como estão no código-fonte, como se fosse numa tag `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: @Sam e se ele quer preservar os espaços? Ele não falou como queria a renderização do texto, e como falei aqui não adicionou espaço algum antes do texto http://prntscr.com/p5qu1i

Comment: É pq vc não fez indentação do texto na div, colocou tudo na mesma linha, mas experimenta fazer assim pra vc ver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRcuf.png .. resumindo, o pre-wrap não serve pra isso. Ele irá renderizar o HTML como se fosse um WYSIWYG.

Comment: @Sam sim, nem no código do AP tem. Por isso podemos ter mais de uma resposta e fica a critério dele escolher qual fica melhor para o caso dele em particular. Abs

Comment: Utilizei o pre-rep no meu elemento filho, funcionou perfeitamente, respeita o padding do elemento pai.

Comment: @VictorHenrique legal jovem, que bom que funcionou ai, no CSS quase sempre existem mais de um jeito de fazer a mesma coisa. Sucesso 